# How to automatically connect VPN when specific App opened? (iOS)

Tags: ios, vpn

Is it possible to make my iPhone automatically connect to a VPN when e.g. Telegram is opened?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is actually a pretty good question; I’m not clear why the initial downvote was submitted.  It does need some details so see my previous comment from Review.  That said, have you though about creating a Shortcut “Wrapper” where you connect to your VPN and then launch your App as needed?  With a little work you could create a “Menu” of VPN apps.  And…. Welcome to Ask Different!

Comment: The VPN may experience a leak because the automation in Apple's Shortcuts app triggers when the app (e.g. Telegram) opens, which may not give enough time for the VPN to establish a secure connection before the app establishes its own connection to its server.

Comment: Delay actions are available to address things like this

Answer (score 1):

Yes it only became possible with a recent upgrade this year. Open Apple’s shortcuts app and add a new automation for when “app opens” (firstly choosing your specific app here, e.g telegram).Then press next and type “connect to VPN” (choosing the prebuilt option that will automatically come up) in the that section. Make sure to press next and finish and you are done.

Comment: The VPN might leak because the VPN connection may not be established instantly when the app (e.g. Telegram) opens. Since the automation in Apple's Shortcuts app triggers when the app opens, it may not allow enough time for the VPN to establish a secure connection before the app establishes its own connection to its server. This could potentially result in the app connecting to its server without going through the VPN, causing a leak of the original IP address and compromising the privacy and security of the connection.